# Need help printing text to a TextArea from another class in Java

Tags: java, textarea

Just need some help printing text to a TextArea for a class project. I have a method that generates 5 random numbers between 0-100 and want it to print to a TextArea but I am unsure on how to do that. (Right now I just have Syste.out.println as a placeholder but I would like to remove that)

```
    public class Interface
{   
    public Interface()
    {

    }

    public static void randomNumber()
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        System.out.println("Generating 5 Random Numbers.");

        for (int randomNum = 1; randomNum <=  5; ++randomNum)
        {
            int randomInt = randomNumber.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println("Random Number: " + randomInt);
        }

    System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}



public class InterfacePanel extends JPanel
{
    private InterfaceController baseController;
    private SpringLayout baseLayout;
    private JButton buttonOne;
    private JButton buttonTwo;
    private JButton buttonThree;
    private JButton buttonFour;
    private JLabel lableOne;
    private JLabel lableTwo;
    private JLabel lableThree;
    private JLabel lableFour;
    private TextArea textField;

    public InterfacePanel(InterfaceController baseController)
    {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.baseController = baseController;
        buttonOne = new JButton("Random Numbers");
        buttonTwo = new JButton("Two");
        buttonThree = new JButton("Three");
        buttonFour = new JButton("Four");
        lableOne = new JLabel("5 Random Numbers");
        lableTwo = new JLabel("Two");
        lableThree = new JLabel("Three");
        lableFour = new JLabel("Four");
        baseLayout = new SpringLayout();
        textField = new TextArea();

        setupPanel();
        setupLayout();
        setupListeners();
    }

    private void setupPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(baseLayout);
        this.add(lableOne);
        this.add(buttonOne);
        this.add(buttonTwo);
        this.add(buttonThree);
        this.add(buttonFour);
        this.add(lableTwo);
        this.add(lableThree);
        this.add(lableFour);
        this.add(textField);
    }

    private void setupLayout()

    private void setupListeners()
    {
        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
            {
                Interface.randomNumber();
            }
        });

        buttonTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
            {

            }
        });

        buttonThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
            {

            }
        });

        buttonFour.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter of `JTextArea` in `randomNumber()` method.

```
public static void randomNumber(JTextArea myText){
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        System.out.println("Generating 5 Random Numbers.");

        for (int randomNum = 1; randomNum <=  5; ++randomNum)
        {
            int randomInt = randomNumber.nextInt(5);
            myText.setText(myText.getText() + randomInt + "\n");
        }

    System.out.println("Done.");

}
```

And call `randomNumber()` method in `InterfacePanel` class this way

```
Interface.randomNumber(textField);
```